# ImageGallery won't update from other class

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, binding, inotifypropertychanged

So I'm attempting to download an image in byte from a server, but the image won't display. I get a proper byte-Array and rezise it. It works adding Picture from the imagegallerypagemodel but doesn't work when adding them from the IssuePageModel. So I suspect either the class is instanced wrongly or notifyproperty doesn't work. I've attempted to only add the relevant parts, but can add anything missing.

The Collection

```
 public class ImageGalleryPageModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<ImageModel> Images
        {
            get { return images; }
        }

    private ObservableCollection<ImageModel> images = new ObservableCollection<ImageModel>();
```

This works adding the Pictures from this class

```
 private async Task ExecutePickCommand()
        {
            MediaFile file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync();

            if (file == null)
                return;

            byte[] imageAsBytes;
            using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                file.GetStream().CopyTo(memoryStream);
                file.Dispose();
                imageAsBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            }

            if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                IImageResizer resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResizer>();
                imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

                ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
                Images.Add(new ImageModel { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });
            }
        }
```

Then I load the issuepagemodel for a second time, here is the instance of the imagegallerypagemodel

```
public class IssuePageModel : FreshBasePageModel, INotifyPropertyChanged
{


 public ImageGalleryPageModel ImageGalleryViewModel { get; set; } = new ImageGalleryPageModel();
```

Then I download the images and put them into the Collection, the notifyproperty is triggered, I can see when debugging it steps onto the get, but can't see it on the set part though.

```
 private void AddTheImages(int imageIssueId)
        {
            var imageData = App.Client.GetImage(imageIssueId);

            byte[] imageAsBytes = imageData.Item1;

            if (imageAsBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                IImageResizer resizer = DependencyService.Get<IImageResizer>();
                imageAsBytes = resizer.ResizeImage(imageAsBytes, 1080, 1080);

                ImageSource imageSource = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));
                ImageGalleryViewModel.Images.Add(new ImageModel { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });
            }
        }
```

Entire Xaml

```
  <freshMvvm:FreshBaseContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false" xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:freshMvvm="clr-namespace:FreshMvvm;assembly=FreshMvvm"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:ASFT.Converters;assembly=ASFT"
         xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:ASFT.PageModels;assembly=ASFT"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ASFT.Controls;assembly=ASFT"
         x:Class="ASFT.Pages.IssuePage" Padding="4,25,4,4" x:Name="IssuePages">
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="Labelfont" TargetType="Label">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="Medium" />
        </Style>
        <converters:DateTextConverter x:Key="DateToTextConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<Grid BackgroundColor="Black">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="50" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Top Navigation Bar RETURN TO EVENTS-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" RowSpacing="20">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FBB040">
            <Label Text="    &lt;   EVENTS" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnGoToListCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
                </Label.GestureRecognizers>
            </Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding LocationText}" TextColor="Black"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>


    <ScrollView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="15" Padding="0,30,0,0">

            <!--Category-->
            <Label Text="CATEGORY"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040" Padding="2" HeightRequest="40">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Spacing="6" HeightRequest="40">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding TitleEx}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" HeightRequest="40"
                           BackgroundColor="Black" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <!--Title-->
            <Label Text="TITLE" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040" Padding="2" HeightRequest="40">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             Spacing="6" HeightRequest="40">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding TitleEx}" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center"
                           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" HeightRequest="40"
                           BackgroundColor="Black" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <!--PictureGallery-->
            <Label Text="IMAGES" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                   Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Grid BindingContext="{Binding ImageGalleryViewModel}">

                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="128" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <controls:ImageGalleryControl Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}">
                    <controls:ImageGalleryControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Source}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                                <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer
                                        Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.PreviewImageCommand, Source={x:Reference IssuePages}}"
                                        CommandParameter="{Binding ImageId}" />
                                </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Image>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:ImageGalleryControl.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:ImageGalleryControl>
                <Grid Grid.Row="1">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Add photo" Command="{Binding CameraCommand}" />
                    <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Pick photo" Command="{Binding PickCommand}" />
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="{Binding ImageText}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" />

            <!--Description-->
            <Label Text="DESCRIPTION" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Frame Padding="2" OutlineColor="#FBB040">
                <Editor Text="{Binding DescriptionEx}" HeightRequest="100" BackgroundColor="Black" TextColor="White" />
            </Frame>

            <!--Grid for Status and Severity-->
            <Grid HorizontalOptions="Center">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--Severity-->
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Text="SEVERITY" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}"  />

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Image Source="severity_5.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding Severity5Opacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}"  CommandParameter="severity_5.png" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Image Source="severity_4.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding Severity4Opacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="severity_4.png"  />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                    <Image Source="severity_3.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding Severity3Opacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="severity_3.png"  />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3">
                    <Image Source="severity_2.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding Severity2Opacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="severity_2.png" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="4">
                    <Image Source="severity_1.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding Severity1Opacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="severity_1.png" />
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>


                <!--Status-->
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="STATUS" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="Micro" Text="STATUS" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White"
                       Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" IsVisible="True" />
                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="0">
                    <Image Source="statusUnresolved.png" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding StatusUnresolvedOpacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="statusUnresolved.png"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="4">
                    <Image Source="statusInProgress.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding StatusInProgressOpacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="statusInProgress.png"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>

                <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="4">
                    <Image Source="statusDone.png" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="40" Opacity="{Binding StatusDoneOpacity}">
                        <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnStatusClickedCommand}" CommandParameter="statusDone.png"/>
                        </Image.GestureRecognizers>
                    </Image>
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

            <!--Date Created-->
            <Label Text="TIME AND DATE: " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040" BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="2">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0"
                             BackgroundColor="Black" HeightRequest="40">
                    <Label Text=" " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                           Margin="1" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding CreatedEx, Converter={StaticResource DateToTextConverter}}"
                           Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                           VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <!--REPORTED BY-->
            <Label Text="REPORTED BY: " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" />
            <Frame OutlineColor="#FBB040" BackgroundColor="Black" Padding="2">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0" Padding="1" BackgroundColor="Black"
                             HeightRequest="40">
                    <Label Text=" " Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}" TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding CreatedByEx}" Style="{StaticResource Labelfont}"
                           TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <!--Map View-->
            <Grid>
                <Grid.BindingContext>
                    <maps:TkMapPageModel/>
                </Grid.BindingContext>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="50" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                       Text="Tap and hold on map to set/move pin" Font="Large" />
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <RelativeLayout x:Name="MapRelativeLayout" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HeightRequest="920" WidthRequest="300" />
                </StackLayout>
                <StackLayout Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Orientation="Vertical" Spacing="0">
                    <Label Text="{Binding MapText}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" TextColor="White" />
                </StackLayout>
            </Grid>

            <Button Text="Submit"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                    BackgroundColor="#FBB040" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!--Bottom Navigation Bar-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="2">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal"
                     HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="5" BackgroundColor="White">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FBB040">
                <Image Source="photo2.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="Center">
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FBB040">
                <Image Source="photo2.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="100" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="Center">
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FBB040">
                <Image Source="showmap.png" WidthRequest="100" HeightRequest="60" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And as I repeat, it works when adding from the imagegallerypagemodel but not from the other class IssuePageModel

```
public class ImageGalleryControl : ScrollView
    {

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create<ImageGalleryControl, IList>(
            view => view.ItemsSource,
            default(IList),
            BindingMode.TwoWay,
            propertyChanging: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanging();
            },
            propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) => {
                ((ImageGalleryControl)bindableObject).ItemsSourceChanged(bindableObject, oldValue, newValue);
            }
        );

    public IList ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IList)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Images` in your model is an `ObservableCollection` which works a lot like a list. When you add an image you're not going to hit the `set` because you're not changing the collection, you're adding to the existing collection. This is the correct way... The `ObservableCollection` contains the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface which means there's a `CollectionChanged` event you can subscribe to and listen for changes. When using XAML binding in any itemssource it should automatically be listening and handling this event for you but in the code behind or anywhere in your own code you will most likely need to do this.

Just remember that the collection reference can change also so you need to handle for that as well.  Here's an example of how to properly handle the `ObservableCollection` from model to model.

```
public class ExampleModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<string> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get => names;
        set
        {
            names = value;

            //Only called if I change the collection reference i.e. make a new ObservableCollection or assign it to another exising reference.
            //Not called adding or removing items from existing collection.
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Names)));
        }
    }
}
```

....

```
public class ExampleViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private readonly ExampleModel ExampleModel;
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<string> names = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    public ExampleViewModel()
    {
        ExampleModel = new ExampleModel();
        ExampleModel.PropertyChanged += ExampleModel_PropertyChanged;
        Names = ExampleModel.Names;
        if (Names != null) Names.CollectionChanged += Names_CollectionChanged;
    }

    private void ExampleModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(ExampleModel.Names):
                //Here we reassign the entire collection if it changes.
                if (Names != null) Names.CollectionChanged -= Names_CollectionChanged;
                Names = ExampleModel.Names;
                if (Names != null) Names.CollectionChanged += Names_CollectionChanged;
                break;
        }            
    }

    private void Names_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var item in e.OldItems) Names.Remove((string)item);
        foreach (var item in e.NewItems) Names.Add((string)item);
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> Names
    {
        get => names;
        set
        {
            names = value;

            //Only called if I change the collection reference i.e. make a new ObservableCollection or assign it to another exising reference.
            //Not called adding or removing items from existing collection.
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Names)));
        }
    }

}
```

NOTE:  This example is just to give you a clearer idea of how it works and may not be the cleanest way to implement the two.  If know they are both ObservableCollections then that's fine but at min we should probably assume they are IEnumerable and handle this slightly differently.  Either way... But you need to handle it manually in your code and the XAML should handle this for you when binding to an ItemsSource.

Comment: It seems like now that I think about it, I've been approaching this wrong? Maybe it is the IList itemsource I should send into? But how do I get a reference to it when I declare the code in xaml, like I did in above "  <controls:ImageGalleryControl"? or now I'm confused, it works sending into the observable Collection from the ImageGalleryPage, so should be same there...

Comment: @JsonDork  I've updated the answer with an example that may help clarify things some.

Comment: Hi Michael! Great example, but I get a bit way to confused on how to apply this. Which is the issuepagemodel, the gallerycontrol and the gallerypagemodel?

Comment: @JsonDork  I've got to run to work but if you look at how I'm listening to the ObservableCollection for items being added / removed in the ExampleViewModel I think it'll click in.  You're either adding or removing items or you're resetting the entire collection.  Either way you need to handle for both to capture the changes.

Comment: But why are there two obseravble Collections that are the same? Not sure what you want me to change

Comment: @JsonDork Ok, so there are two different things here but I see what you're asking. In a nut shell it sounds like you have IssuePageModel on a different instance than the ImageGalleryPageModel but I can't tell for sure. If you don't mind post the entire XAML so that I can see all the references and binding. If there's code behind post all of that also. For my original answer I thought you were more concerned about the reason you were hitting the get and not the set. See my next comment about that.

Comment: @JsonDork The reason you are hitting the get is because you are asking for the Images in this line ```ImageGalleryViewModel.Images.Add(new ImageModel { Source = imageSource, OrgImage = imageAsBytes });```.  However; you're not setting the Images but rather adding to the Images.  That's why you're not hitting the setter which is good.  If you hit the setter you are replacing the Images with a new ObservableCollection altogether.

Comment: Yes, I understand about the setter being meaningless this case, so I removed it. But yeah, you're right. ImageGalleryPagemodel is a different class than issuepagemodel if that is what you mean. I added the entire XAML class as you requested. :)

Comment: @JsonDork  Ok, I've looked it over and I can't see where you're setting the main BindingContext.  I do see you setting the Grid BindingContext to ImageGalleryViewModel.  This is fine so I'm assuming that the entire view has a BindingContext of IssuePageModel. If that's the case then you're code is logically ok; however, the you're trying to reference the IssuePages in the Datatemplate with x:Reference which doesn't work for Datatemplates because they aren't not part of the same logical tree.  I'll continue on another comment.

Comment: @JsonDork Once you enter the DataTemplate you're not longer binding to the anything else with the View so to speak.  Imagine the DataTemplate as a standalone resource that can be reused and only expects a DataType to bind to with no knowledge or logic of anything above it.  Placing the commands in the ImageGalleryViewModel is actually better in this situation and should be fine.  You just have to rethink the flow a lil here but you got it. Also, if I may recommend, moving DataTemplates to their own resource as well as reducing the code on the view by making smaller views and embedding.

Comment: I had no idea how to fix that, but I just decided to give up and merge the ImageGalleryPageModel into its parents page the issuepagemodel, which now works as I can refer the exact same instance this time.